# Get product price from getQuoteItem?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

We write the observer for updating the product price while add to cart.i have write the observer but can't get item price for currently added product in cart.

In the below code, how to get the item price of currently added item.

```
public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
 {

    $event = $observer->getEvent();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento

Comment: Hey Rat, if you find a solution let us know or mark an answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento)

I think what you need from there is simply this part 
In your Observer.php you would need something like this

```
public function _construct()
  {
  }

public function getNewPrice()
  {
    //Your new functionality here
    //
    $newprice = "";

    return $newprice;
  }

 public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
 {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
    $new_price = $this->getNewPrice();
    $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
    $quote_item->save();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
public function updatePrice( Varien_Event_Observer $observer ) 
 {
$quote = $observer->getQuote();
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $quote_item) {
        // get items detail here
        echo $quote_item->getPrice();

}

}
```